# Moving a Node from main to popup window causes HierarchyRequestError

Tags: javascript, html, dom, popup, nodes

I have a problem with JavaScript. I can't find out why IE throws an HierarchyRequestError in the following part of code.
I create am map (e.g. GoogleMap or OpenStreetMap) in the mainscreen within a div-container. That node has the ID "map-canvas". By pressing a button I want to move that map into a popup-window. Therefore I load a HTML file including just a div-container with the ID "mapCol" and a div-container with the ID "map-canvas-pop" in it. In that container is a loading image by default.

When the DOM is ready in the popup window I want to move the map-node from main window into the popup window.
While using Firefox or Chrome it works fine without any error. Just with the InternetExplorer it will cause an exception.

The first part of the code that may be important for the question:

```
/**
 * Moving the map to a popup window or back to main screen
 */
var _My = function(){
//[...] some other stuff
    var __mapWindowHandler = null;
    var __clonedMap = null;

    //Attach the onclose and onresize events when popup DOM is ready
    var __attachEventToPopup = function(){
        if (!__mapWindowHandler || !__mapWindowHandler.MyPopup || !__mapWindowHandler.MyPopup.setResizeEvent){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                __attachEventToPopup();
            }, 250);
            return;
        }
        //MyPopup is a "JS-Class" within the popup HTML Structure
        __mapWindowHandler.MyPopup.setResizeEvent(function(){
            if (_My.Map.sizeUpdate 
                && typeof(_My.Map.sizeUpdate) === 'function')
            _My.Map.sizeUpdate();
        });


        if (typeof(__mapWindowHandler.onbeforeunload) === 'object'){
            __mapWindowHandler.onbeforeunload = function(event){
                __toggleMapPopup(false, true);
            };
        }
    }; //__attachEventToPopup()

    //Opens a popup and move the current map with all configurations into that window
    //or remove popup and put the map back to the main page
    var __toggleMapPopup = function(popupAlreadyStarted, isCloseEvent){
        if (!isCloseEvent && ((popupAlreadyStarted && popupAlreadyStarted === true) || __mapWindowHandler === null)){
            //Map ius not in popup or popup is closed
            var container;
            var w, h;
            if (!popupAlreadyStarted || popupAlreadyStarted !== true) {
                container = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
                w = container && container.offsetWidth > 100 ? (container.offsetWidth || 800 ) : 800;
                h = container && container.offsetHeight > 300 ? (container.offsetHeight || 600) : 600;
                __mapWindowHandler = window.open('index.php?getMapHtmlStructure=true',"MyMapWindow", "width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",left=10,top=10,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,menubar=no,location=no,dependent=yes,toolbar=no,status=no");
            }
            __mapWindowHandler.focus();

            var mapElem = __mapWindowHandler.document.getElementById('map-canvas-pop');
            if (!mapElem){
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    __toggleMapPopup(true);
                }, 1000);
                return;
            }
            var width = document.getElementById('rightCol').style.width;
            container = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

            //backup the map-node to be able to restore it when popup isn't accessable anymore
            __clonedMap = container.cloneNode();
                    /* PART 1 */
```

This part will throw the exception in IE:

```
                    /* PART 1 */
            try {
                __mapWindowHandler.document.getElementById('mapCol').appendChild(container);
                //This throws a "HierarchyRequestError" in IE
                //It works fine with Firefox and Chrome
            }
            catch (e){
                alert('Map could not be moved to popup.' + "\n" + e.message);
                __mapWindowHandler.close();
                __mapWindowHandler = null;
                return;
            }
                    /* PART 2 */
```

The rest of the code:

```
                    /* PART 2 */
            __attachEventToPopup();
        } //if (!isCloseEvent [...])
        else {
            //Map is in popup window
            if (__mapWindowHandler){
                var container = __mapWindowHandler.document ? (__mapWindowHandler.document.getElementById('map-canvas-pop') || __mapWindowHandler.document.getElementById('map-canvas') || __clonedMap) : __clonedMap;
                document.getElementById('rightCol').innerHTML = '';
                document.getElementById('rightCol').appendChild(container);
                __mapWindowHandler.close();
                __mapWindowHandler = null;
            }
            else
                document.getElementById('rightCol').appendChild(__clonedMap);

            if (_My.Map.sizeUpdate 
                    && typeof(_My.Map.sizeUpdate) === 'function')
                _My.Map.sizeUpdate();
        } //else
    }; //__toggleMapPopup()

//[...] some other stuff
} //_My()
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same problem before and found out, that only solution to solve this is to avoid actual node cloning, but rework component with map to be serializable. (When working with different windows it is also better practice than element cloning.)

From my experience with cloning there were problems with transmitting event listeners, some of element properties, references etc.

The IE problem is caused by the fact that IE don't allow to copy nodes between documents. (In older versions you also weren't able to add a DOM element created in one document to another document.)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove container before appending it again:

```
//backup the map-node to be able to restore it when popup 
isn't accessable anymore
        container.parentElement.removeChild(container);
        __clonedMap = container.cloneNode();
```

Hope it helps!